# iOS - How to get rid of "app is using your location" notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm using Google Map SDK 1.8.1 on ios 8,
I set `Allow Location Access While Using The App`:

[image]

And then everytime I using `GMSMapView` and `Home`, this one shows up.
(When there is an `UIViewController` that contains `GMSMapView` in navigation stack)

How can I dismiss it programmatically ?
Thanks you.

---

edit: sorry, I didn't make my question clear enough.

What I mean is how can I stop `GMSMapView` from using Location Service when users press `Home` button, I think that will do the trick.

I tried `Google Map`'s app, the notification view does disappear when you `Home`, so I think it is possible.

Comment: I fear you can't. Application can not use user location with out the knowledge of user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prevent the banner from displaying while you're using the user's location, it's information for the user provided by the system, for them to make informed decisions about which apps they share their location with and when.

Even if you found a way to do this, I'd be extremely surprised if it would get through app review. There's no specific rule about it, as it's not an option in the API anyway, but the gist of [the guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#location) is that the user should know what you're doing with their location, and when you're tracking it:

> ### 4. Location
>
> 4.1 : Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected

---

#### Edit - responding to home button press

In order to stop using location when the user presses the home button, you need to subscribe to notifications about entering the background. When you initialise your class which is using location, register for the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Then, in the method which is called for that notification, stop using location:

```
-(void)appWillResignActive:(NSNotification*)note
{
    //stop using location here. I'm not familar with GMSMapView, but assuming you have a reference to the map view, the documentation suggests this:
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = NO;
}
```

You may also want to register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` so that you can pick location services back up again when the user opens your app again from the app switcher.

Comment: thx you. Sorry my question causes some misunderstanding, I edited my question, please re-check.

Comment: FYI: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification notification will also raise when user will get alert of "Allow push notification/ Allow location" kind of system alert.

Answer (score 3):

No way to hide it. Even if I stop Location updates.

**One thing is for sure:**

You must use `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in `info.plist`

**and**

request `requestAlwaysAuthorization` from `LocationManager`

**in order to**

hide the blue bar forever (and still have the background capability because of Location updates).

PS: I've seen someone speaking about having the blue line disappear after a while but that did not happen to me. Can anyone confirm of auto hiding blue bar?